# Get Document Library Size using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the exact size of SharePoint document libraries.

```
$listSize = 0
foreach ($item in $list.items) 
{ 
    $listSize += ($item.file).length
}

$listStorage = $listSize
Write-Host "Size of List : " $listStorage
```

But When I have actually compare size of Document library from SharePoint site settings --> Storage Metrics,  it shows different.

Is the way I'm working is right. 
Please suggest some code.

Comment: It will certainly differ if you enable versioning.

Comment: I think you just got three answers as a variation on your own solution. I would say Alexey has the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

Please find the below script, I used it to get the size.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
$siteURL = "YOUR SITE URL HERE" 
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteURL)
CLS
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    foreach ($list in $web.Lists)
    {
        if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary")   
        {
            $listSize = 0
            foreach ($item in $list.items) 
            { 
                $listSize += ($item.file).length
            }
            Write-Host "Web Name: " -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black -NoNewline
            Write-Host $web.Title -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black 
            Write-Host "Library Name: " -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black -NoNewline
            Write-Host $list.Title -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black 
            Write-Host "Size: " -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black -NoNewline
            Write-Host ([Math]::Round(($listSize/1KB),2)) "KB" -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black 
            Write-Host "---------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try with below script.

```
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
  $SizeofDocLib=0  
  $count=0
  foreach ($list in $web.Lists)
    {

        if($list.BaseTemplate -eq "DocumentLibrary")   
            {
                 $listSize = 0
                 foreach ($item in $list.items) 
                    { 
                       $listSize += ($item.file).length
                    }
                 $listSize= [Math]::Round(($listSize/1MB),2)                                       
                 Write-Host $listSize "MB "
                 $SizeofDocLib+=$listSize
            }
     }
Write-Host Size :" "($SizeofDocLib/1024) "GB"
Write-Host $count
}
```

I used to get the size of document library with above.

Answer (score 1):

```
function GetFolderSizeInBytes ($Folder)
{
   [long]$folderSize = 0  
   foreach ($file in $Folder.Files)
   {
      $folderSize += $file.Length;
   }
   foreach ($fd in $Folder.SubFolders)
   {
      $folderSize += GetFolderSize -Folder $fd
   }
   return $folderSize
}
$sizeInBytes = GetFolderSizeInBytes($list.RootFolder)
$sizeInKb = $sizeInBytes/1024
$sizeInMb = $sizeInBytes/1024/1024
$sizeInGb = $sizeInBytes/1024/1024/1024
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

I had this same question, with a few tweaks, but I had a problem most of the other answers here don't address - what if your document library has sub-folders?

I've written a script that will give you the number of actual files in a document library (that's not including folders) and the total size of everything in the library, recursively.

```
# Gets an object with NumFiles and TotalSize properties,
# which correspond with those of the list you pass in.
function Get-ListFileInfo($SPList)
{
    $name = $SPList.Title
    Write-Verbose "  $($name)"

    if($SPList.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary")
    {
        $fileInfo =  New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop (
            @{'NumFiles'=0;
            'TotalSize'=0}
        )

        $folder = $SPList.RootFolder

        $fileInfo = Get-DocLibFolderFileInfo $folder $true
        $fileInfo.NumFiles = $SPList.Items.Count
    }
    # You could expand this to other list types, too.
    # I left that out for brevity's sake.

    Write-Output $fileInfo
}

# Recursive function to get the filesize information from a folder
# Pass this the RootFolder of your SPList and it'll return the filesizes.
# used to count Files in here, too, but modified for accuracy
function Get-DocLibFolderFileInfo($SPFolder, [boolean] $recursive = $true)
{
    $filesInfo = New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop (
        @{'NumFiles'=$null;
        'TotalSize'=0})

    Write-Verbose "  Folder: $($SPFolder.Name)"

    if($SPFolder.Name -ne "Forms")
    {
        $files = $SPFolder.Files

        $filesHere = $files.Count

        Write-Verbose "    # Files: $($filesHere)"

        for($etr = 0;$etr -lt $filesHere; $etr++)
        {
            #$item = $files[$etr]
            $file = $files[$etr]
            #$file = ($item.file)
            if($file -ne $null)
            {
                if($file.Name.EndsWith(".aspx"))
                {
                    # skip views and the like, because we don't care.
                    Write-Verbose "    Skipping File: $($file.Name)";
                }
                else
                {
                    $fileSize = $file.Length
                    $filesInfo.TotalSize += $fileSize

                    Write-Verbose "    Filename: $($file.Name)"
                    Write-Verbose "      Size: $($fileSize)"
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Warning "    Null file found?"
            }
        }
    }

    # Now recurse into subfolders
    if($SPFolder.SubFolders.Count -ne 0 -AND $recursive -eq $true)
    {
        $subFolders  = $SPFolder.SubFolders
        for($etr = 0;$etr -lt $subFolders.Count; $etr++)
        {
            $subFolder = $subFolders[$etr]
            $subFolderInfo = Get-DocLibFolderFileInfo $subFolder $true
            $filesInfo.TotalSize += $subFolderInfo.TotalSize;
        }
    }

    Write-Output $filesInfo
}
```

So to use these functions, just pass in your `SPList` object to `Get-ListFileInfo` and deal with the information it returns.

Answer (score 1):

```
function GetWebSizes ($StartWeb)
{
$web = Get-SPWeb $StartWeb
[long]$total = 0
$total += GetWebSize -Web $web
$total += GetSubWebSizes -Web $web
$totalInMb = ($total/1024)/1024
$totalInMb = "{0:N2}" -f $totalInMb
$totalInGb = (($total/1024)/1024)/1024
$totalInGb = "{0:N2}" -f $totalInGb
write-host "Total size of all sites below" $StartWeb "is" $total "Bytes,"
write-host "which is" $totalInMb "MB or" $totalInGb "GB"
$web.Dispose()
}

function GetWebSize ($Web)
{
[long]$subtotal = 0
foreach ($folder in $Web.Folders)
{
    $subtotal += GetFolderSize -Folder $folder
}
write-host "Site" $Web.Title "is" $subtotal "KB"
return $subtotal
}

function GetSubWebSizes ($Web)
{
[long]$subtotal = 0
foreach ($subweb in $Web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser())
{
    [long]$webtotal = 0
    foreach ($folder in $subweb.Folders)
    {
        $webtotal += GetFolderSize -Folder $folder
    }
    write-host "Site" $subweb.Title "is" $webtotal "Bytes"
    $subtotal += $webtotal
    $subtotal += GetSubWebSizes -Web $subweb
}
return $subtotal
}

function GetFolderSize ($Folder)
{
[long]$folderSize = 0  
foreach ($file in $Folder.Files)
{
    $folderSize += $file.Length;
}
foreach ($fd in $Folder.SubFolders)
{
    $folderSize += GetFolderSize -Folder $fd
}
return $folderSize
}
```

**Once you have run the script, you can call it with the following PowerShell command:**

```
GetWebSizes -StartWeb <StartURL>
```

Using a start URL allows you to perform a size check from any site in the hierarchy – not just the top level site. In the example below, I ran it against the URL http://portal, but could also choose to run it from a sub-site, if required:

```
PS C:\> GetWebSizes -StartWeb http://portal
Site Intranet is 12763801 KB
Site Hello is 581759 Bytes
Site Team Site is 604175 Bytes
Total size of all sites below http://portal is 13949735 Bytes,
which is 13.30 MB or 0.01 GB
```

Reference:-

[Get SharePoint Library Size with PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/01/get-sharepoint-library-size-powershell.html) and [Powershell Script to find document library size where versions are enabled](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/99064e4c-c93f-4894-9bc2-bfd9bef47b3c/powershell-script-to-find-document-library-size-where-versions-are-enabled?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Comment: This script works for me but does this script calculates the size of each file's version also?